# What is the equivalent of UIImageView animationImages in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm experimenting with SpriteKit, I'm building a humanoid character who uses multiple image files for facial expressions. So I can build up an SKSpriteNode to depict this character using a series of other sprites, i.e nodes for each arm and legs and the head, but I want to use multiple nodes for the face. In standard UIKit, you can use a UIImageView with an array of images and it will automatically animate through that array with the duration you set.

```
NSArray *animationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"],
                                      ..., nil];

UIImageView *animationView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 260)];

[self.view addSubview:animationView];    

animationView.animationImages=animationArray;
animationView.animationDuration=1.5;
animationView.animationRepeatCount=0;

[animationView startAnimating];
```

What would be the equivalent in SpriteKit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `SKAction` to create animations, like this:

```
SKAction *animation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:_animationArray timePerFrame:0.1];
[self runAction:animation withKey:@"myAnimation"]; // self is e.g. SKSpriteNode object
```

[SKAction class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

[SKNode class reference (Running Actions)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013023-CH1-SW2)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a [texture atlas](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW15) and cycle through the atlas images with a `SKAction`. Here's a good tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/45152/sprite-kit-tutorial-animations-and-texture-atlases